# Pure CSS tab containers active tab

Tags: html, css, sass, tabs

I've got a problem. I have a pure CSS tab container. But when I click on a tab, it should become active in some way.

I already tried it with a `<input type="radio" />` and a `<label for="foo">`
But then the anchor `<a href="#tabX"></a>` does not work anymore.

Any ideas?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/uvvwspx8/)

Comment: That would only be possible if tab trigger element was located below the targeted element in the DOM tree. And in a solution with labels and radio buttons, the label would do the job of the link. (Which means you would lose “bookmarkability”.)

Comment: @Morpheus Thanks, but I need it to work in IE10/11, Safari (10.1), FF, Chrome (wich it does) and Edge! So that's a whole bunch of browsers, and it only works in chrome. Thanks for your answer tho! :)

Comment: Whoops, deleted the comment :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already using hash `#` you can use make use of the pseudo class `:target`.

To show how this works I added extra `span` to be able to target both the anchor `a` and the `div`.

The main 3 things that make this work is the `span`, the `:target ~ ...` and `#tab1:target ~ ...` rules.

1. Having the `span` placed before we can use the sibling selector to target 1 or more elements with only 1 hash.
2. With the `:target ~ ...` rule we reset the initilly showed tab and its content when a hash exist
3. Finally we use each `#tab1:target ~ ...` rule to mark the selected tab and show its content

Also see comment in CSS, which explain the steps used.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hideme {
  display: none;
}

.tabcontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
.tabcontainer .tab {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* set the first link's background and show its div on page load */
ul li:first-child a,
.tab:first-child {
  background: #638DB2;
  display: block;
}

/* reset the first link's background and hide its div when a hash tag exist */
:target ~ ul [href="#tab1"] {
  background: black;
}
:target ~ .tabcontainer #tab1div {
  display: none;
}

/* set the hashed/targeted link's background and show its div */
#tab1:target ~ ul [href="#tab1"],
#tab1:target ~ .tabcontainer #tab1div {
  background: #638DB2;
  display: block;
}
#tab2:target ~ ul [href="#tab2"],
#tab2:target ~ .tabcontainer #tab2div {
  background: #FF4C43;
  display: block;
}
#tab3:target ~ ul [href="#tab3"],
#tab3:target ~ .tabcontainer #tab3div {
  background: #C1CC14;
  display: block;
}
#tab4:target ~ ul [href="#tab4"],
#tab4:target ~ .tabcontainer #tab4div {
  background: #ADB257;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span id="tab1" class="hideme"></span>
<span id="tab2" class="hideme"></span>
<span id="tab3" class="hideme"></span>
<span id="tab4" class="hideme"></span>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabcontainer">
  <div id="tab1div" class="tab">
    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2div" class="tab">
    2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab3div" class="tab">
    3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab4div" class="tab">
    4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have the hideme content? I do not really NEED a ul. Can also be something else.

Comment: @Refilon If you place the anchor `a` unwrapped, as the `span` is, you can use them instead of the `span`, but if you need to _wrap_ the links in any way, you need _outer_ elements to solve this.

Comment: @Refilon For _outer_ elements you can also use `<input type="radio">` instead of the `span`, though they need to be place at the same place where the `span` is ... so bottom line, you need the extra elements if you wrap the tabs

Comment: Do you have an example without the outer elements? That's a bit cleaner isn't it?

Comment: This is also because the names of the tab can change. So then if it changes, the CSS won't work anymore.

Comment: @Refilon There is one more way...I think it will work...when done I notify you

Comment: @Refilon Btw, you won't be able to change the `id` in any solution, with or w/o outer elements, and not use _outer elements_ is not cleaner, as when the are needed, they are needed. Also, you won't be able to _bookmark_ if to use `input radio` elements. So is that needed?

Comment: @Refilon Tried another alternative but it won't work. The answer I gave is the only CSS way. If you drop the link wrapper (`ul`/`li`) you can use the links instead of the `span`. If to use `input radio` you can't use `:target`, and will need to place the `input`'s where the `span` is now.

Comment: @Refilon So what do you mean by _the names of the tabs can change_, and how do you see that will affect the solution?

Comment: The id's are not static. The contentmanager can change the ID's. Also there can be more than 4 tabs. Or less.

Comment: @Refilon A very important requirement not mentioned in the question. Since both the `:target` and `input`/`label` technique both require a unique `id` you won't be able to solve this using CSS only with the existing markup. So would a markup change be possible, or the _contentmanager_ might mess with that too? ... And is Flexbox allowed to be used?

Comment: Well, I can make the ID's all look like tab[number]. The only thing is, I do not know how many tabs there will be. So I think I'll just use some jQuery, that's much easier. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Refilon Since that is how the existing `id` logic looks like, it is quite easy to simply add _enough_ of CSS rules and it will just work. I mean it is much better to have a few too many CSS rules than to have to rely on script. With the CSS the links will be _bookmarkable_ with a unique url

Comment: @Asons nice CSS-only answer for bookmark able tabs, thanks. I took it and expanded it, have added the result in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a script version, I've just edited the source code as the snippet and added some jQuery functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentTab = $("#buttonTab1")
  
  $("#buttonTab1").click(function(){
    currentTab.removeClass();
    currentTab = $(this);
   $(this).addClass("tab1")
  });
  
 $("#buttonTab2").click(function(){
    currentTab.removeClass();
    currentTab = $(this);
   $(this).addClass("tab2")
  });
  
  $("#buttonTab3").click(function(){
    currentTab.removeClass();
    currentTab = $(this);
   $(this).addClass("tab3")
  });
  
  $("#buttonTab4").click(function(){
    currentTab.removeClass();
    currentTab = $(this);
   $(this).addClass("tab4")
  });

});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;  
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  background: #333;    
}
ul li a {
   color: #FFF;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.tabcontainer {
  width: 100%;  
}
.tab:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.tab {
  position: absolute;  
}  
.tab:target {
  display: block;
}
.tab1 {
  background: #638DB2;
}
.tab2 {
  background: #FF4C43;
}
.tab3 {
  background: #C1CC14;
}
.tab4 {
  background: #ADB257;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="buttonTab1" class = "tab1" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="buttonTab2" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a id="buttonTab3" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a id="buttonTab4" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabcontainer">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab tab1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab tab2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab tab3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab tab4">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @Asons answer and expanded it into a complete mini-site, with the CSS-only tab solution using IDs in the URL, then added jump links that work within each tab’s content with JavaScript and the HTML `data-` attribute. This is necessary because the CSS tab solutions already uses IDs, so we then need JavaScript to keep the current tab in view and jump to the in-tab content.

Here's the [result on GitHub](https://daveeveritt.github.io/css-sibling-tabs/): CSS-only tabs with optional JavaScript jump links within each tab’s content. Using naming/numbering conventions I've written the code to be scalable (as many or few tabs as you need, etc.).

You can also see these [CSS tabs working here](https://daveeveritt.github.io/css-sibling-tabs/) on GitHub pages.